# React native Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, concatenation

I'm training in React Native with JS.
In my code I wrote this function as in the class:

```
_loadFilms() {
    if (this.searchedText.length > 0) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true }) // Lancement du chargement
      getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText(this.searchedText, this.page+1).then(data => {
        this.page = data.page
        this.totalPages = data.total_pages
        this.setState({
          films: [ ...this.state.films, ...data.results ],
          isLoading: false
        })
      })
    }
}
```

But I have an error like this:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread
> non-iterable instance.]                              at
> node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\nonIterableSpread.js:2:8 in
> _nonIterableSpread                                   at node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\toConsumableArray.js:10:94 in
> _toConsumableArray                                 at Components\Search.js:28:18 in
> getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText.then$argument_0
> at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:11
> in tryCallOne                              at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:14 in setImmediate$argument_0                - ... 6 more stack frames
> from framework internals

**Indeed** the result is not corresponding
Could you help me please?

Comment: Well, either `this.state.films` isn't iterable or `data.results` isn't iterable, or both. Can you add them to your question? Your initial `films` state and anything that updates it, and the `data` response.

Comment: Oh sorry I wrote this for nothing, I found the error, it was a spelling check error

Comment: Great, quickest fix I've had all day! :p Voting to close as Unreproducible or caused by typo. Cheers.